# Is it good to write a Class Method that the defining and return without use anything about the class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method, objective-c-category

I have a *Currency* class, it is a subclass of *NSManagedObject*, now I want to add a `+(NSString *)localCurrency` class method for it (it will be used in many places), but the defining will not use anything about the *Currency* class, and the return is not an instance of *Currency* class. So is it good to write this method in *Currency* class?

I know `[[NSLocale currentLocal] objectForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode]` will return the local currency code, but I need it exclude some currencies that are not supported by my app.

Or I write this method in a `NSLocal` class category? (That will need to add a new file just to create one method.)

Comment: If your app represents currencies as instances of `Currency` then I don't see anything wrong with a class method that returns some "meta" information about currencies.

Comment: Write stand alone function, if you can't deside where add class method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems reasonable to want to add a "`localCurrency`" class method to a class that is named "`Currency`".

And inside that method, you can do your "`NSLocale`" thing and then do something special (e.g. throw an alert for "Bitcoins aren't currently supported") if the locale currency code isn't supported by your app.